# Lumen transactions

Tags: laravel, transactions, lumen

I'am struggeling to get the transactions at work with laravel lumen, but still no success.
I see alot of DB facade for the transactions, but is there a way that I can use something like this?

There is no clear documentation about transactions in Lumen.

```html
app('db')->transaction(function() {
    // DB work
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: yess you can use  ```app('db')->transaction```

Comment: How about commit and rollback?? How can I use them in this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the closure approach to using transactions. If the closure throws an exception it will automatically be rolled back. if closure pass it will be committed. hope this helps.

```
app('db')->transaction(function() {
    // DB work
});
```

Comment: @KarimCherimoAoulad You should 'upvote' and 'accept' the answer.

Answer (score 2):

yes, here is the proper way to perform you Db transactions in Lumen.

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try 
  { 
   DB::commit();
  } 
  catch (\Exception $e) 
  {
    DB::rollback();
  }`
```

in try before DB::commit(); you can add your code . once all good it will save to db and if any exception occurs it will rollback and will not save data.
Enjoy ! 
Happy Coding